# How avoid executing ScalaTest specification twice, when it's part of a `Suites`

Tags: scala, integration-testing, scalatest

I'm integration testing a Play Framework app using ScalaTest. This:
`org.scalatest.Suites(list-of-specifications)`
executes each test in the *list-of-specifications*. But how can I avoid each specification being executed independently as well? They're being executed twice.

An example:

```
import org.scalatest.{Suites, FreeSpec}

class BrowserSuiteSpec extends Suites(new AnonLoginSpec)
class AnonLoginSpec extends FreeSpec { ... }
```

Now my `AnonLoginSpec` is executed twice – first as part of the BrowserSuiteSpec, then independently, since it's a FreeSpec class. (Changing `AnonLoginSpec` to a trait results in a compilation errror.)

Renaming `AnonLoginSpec` to `AnonLoginSpeX` didn't have any effect — it's still being executed twice. 
<sub>(I thought perhaps ScalaTest was looking for the "Spec" suffix, which I think Specs2 does.)</sub>

[The documentation](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/Suites.html) doesn't mention this issue (as far as I can tell).

Comment: specs2 doesn't look for "*Spec" either and you could run into the same issue you're describing here. This would be solved in several ways depending how you're executing your specifications (from sbt, from the command-line, etc...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using ScalaTest 2.0.M5 or later, you can annotate each suite with [@DoNotDiscover](http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M5/#org.scalatest.DoNotDiscover).  Alternatively, you can bypass discovery and just specify the main suite class name by passing -s MainSuite to the ScalaTest runner.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using 2.0-M4 actually, and as a workaround I declared the suites `abstract` and then ScalaTest ignores them.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using pre 2.0-M5, then you can simply declare the spec `abstract` and then ScalaTest ignores it. So I did this: (and it works; the test is only run from within the `Suites` construct)

```
class BrowserSuiteSpec extends Suites(new AnonLoginSpec {})

abstract class AnonLoginSpec extends FreeSpec { ... }
```

<sub>(I accepted *mpilquist*'s answer anyway (see above) because that's how things are supposed to work in version 2.0.)</sub>